# Use preventDefault() instead of removing attr href

Tags: jquery

When I click the back button, I need to navigate to previous page, and it actually has a  tag where it goes to home page. Rather I should stop it going to home page.

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Instead of removing href attr, How can I use preventDefault(); Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler receives the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) as the first argument, use it to call [preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('#id').click(function(e){
    e.preventdefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('#id').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/9zUuC/2

or just return false:

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/9zUuC/1/

`return false;` is used effectively to do both `event.stopPropogation()` and `event.preventDefault();`

While, `event.preventDefault()` does what its name says: It prevents the default action.

Comment: Yup got it. You missed "event" paramenter in the function. Anyways thanks pal.

Comment: @NizamAli, no I didn't miss it. It is intentional. It will work

Comment: @NizamAli, check out the demos

Comment: The first demo won't work in Firefox, as `event` object isn't exposed to the global scope in this browser. As for the second, you should've at least mention the difference between `return false` and `Event.preventDefault()`.